# Why is the filter trying to compare a string and int32 data types when expressions return an integer?

Tags: matrix, filter, integer, grouping, ssrs-2008-r2

I have adjacent groups in my matrix - the first group in purple is everything for the financial years selected in the parameter (before the current one) and the group in yellow is the current financial year (YTD)

[image: report design]

At the moment I have the following WHERE Clause in my data set which gives me the correct results for the first group

```
WHERE #DocsSales.FinancialYear IN (@FinancialYear) AND 
#DocsSales.FinancialYearEnd < ( CASE WHEN MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) <= 3 THEN YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ELSE YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)+1 END)
```

However, in order to split the data correctly between the two column groups and still use the same data set I believe that I need to move the second part of the WHERE clause (after AND) into the column group filter for each column group (using < for the first group and = for the second group).

I added the filter but I am getting an error message:
[image: filter]

[image: error message]

The field FinancialYear in my query is this:

```
CASE WHEN MONTH(ed.tsg_saledate) <= 3 THEN YEAR(ed.tsg_saledate)
               ELSE YEAR(ed.tsg_saledate)+1 END AS FinancialYearEnd,
```

which according to everything I have read, returns an integer and the filter expression is

```
=IIF(MONTH(NOW())<= 3, YEAR(NOW()),YEAR(NOW())+1)
```

which again according to everything I have read, also returns an integer.

So I have 2 questions really:
1. Am I right to do this using the column group filters?
2. Why is the filter message saying that it is trying to compare a string and int32 data types when both appear to be returning an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the image you have supplied , in group properties fx = text , this needs to be integer

Comment: That cell was greyed out so I didnt think that I could change it but because of your response I selected a different integer field and it updated to integer and then when I re-selected my original FinancialYear field it stayed as an integer but greyed out again.  This has cured the error message - many thanks